# multi page content drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, forms

So i want to create a website which presents information about topics over multiple pages, i.e. say the content was films, one page would be an overview of the film and there would be a button at the bottom which would pull up the films cast etc (think like a multi step signup form).

My current thinking is I could create this as a series of views so have like one view that links to %film/overview, %film/cast etc. As I am still pretty new to drupal I thought I would ask here whether this was the best way to present this type of content, or if there are better options?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best way is to do it with core [Book module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book)

> A book is a set of pages tied together in a hierarchical sequence,
>   perhaps with chapters, sections, subsections, and so on. You can use
>   books for manuals, site resource guides, Frequently Asked Questions
>   (FAQs), or whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a solution using either:

1. [Quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) + [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)
2. [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) ( client-side multipage-step fieldgroups )

For the user interface effects there.

i.e tabbed widget or next/prev field groups.